# Custom post URLs

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

My normal posts publish into `domain/notes/`, so for custom posts I can set `with_front` appropriately so as to not prepend CPT with `notes`.

But is there a way I can then 'push them down a level', so they publish into domain/programs/?

Example: If I create a CPT of `hosts`, I want individual entries to publish as `domain/programs/hosts/post-name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `slug` agument under `rewrite` parameter of `register_post_type()` function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'egister_hosts_post_type' );
function register_hosts_post_type() {
    $args = array(
      // ....
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'programs/hosts' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'hosts', $args );
}
```

As this affect the rewrite rules, you should flush them on activation/deactivation of the plugin:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_register_hosts_post_type' );
function cyb_register_hosts_post_type() {
    $args = array(
      // ....
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'programs/hosts' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'hosts', $args );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_activation_hook' );
function cyb_activation_hook() {
    cyb_register_hosts_post_type();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_deactivation_hook' );
function cyb_deactivation_hook() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Comment: Please, if this answers your question, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow) so other users can find the answer quickly (top-left corner of the answer, there is a check mark bellow the up/down vote buttons).